# Can / should I call firebaseRef.set passing an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

The question title says it all. Here are a couple related pages from the Firebase docs:

- [writing data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/writing-data.html)
- [managing lists](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html)

Is there a better way to update all the items in an "array" on Firebase?

Comment: Check out [Firebase Blog: Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Answer (score 1):

Note that using `.push` on a ref in firebase does not append to an array but rather an array-like object with non-ordinal keys that look like `-JH1w9H0qPJIFu_OF_JO`.  If you want to work with actual JavaScript arrays, you need to treat them as a *unit*.  That is, any time you update a property that contains an array you have to set the entire array -- you can't use Firebase to update individual components of the array.

If you need ordered data, [use priorities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html).

That being said, it is safe to write arrays (`[]`) as properties in Firebase.  If you have a list and you need to update each property of the list, you cycle through the snapshot (once you've retrieved it from the ref using `.value` or the like) using [`.forEach`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/foreach.html).  You can then us `.update` on each individual child.